# Apache 2.4.9 returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I am trying to set up a web server on apache 2.4 (wamp server 2.5) I get an empty page every time I enter my domain name on the browser (www.example.com).

Here's what I've done so far:

1. directed my public ip address to my domain name on godaddy
2. Forwarded port 80 to my local IP address on my router
3. Set my IP adress to static by modifying TCP/IP v4 protocols and also input the proper dns server by obtaing it from ipconfig /all.
4. I made a few modifications on the httpd.conf changed server name to my domain, change listen to my ip adress followed by :80
   changed :

   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted

   I also modified this

   ServerAdmin xxxxxxxx@icloud.com
   DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
   ServerName www.xxxxxxxxx.com
   ErrorLog "logs/www.xxxxxxxxx.com-error_log"
   TransferLog "logs/www.xxxxxxxx.com-access_log"
    
   I know is a total disaster. Can you please give some direction?
   I wold truly appreciate that.

Technical details:

- Apache 2.4
- wamp server 2.5
- Windows 10

Comment: Assuming you are on a residential internet connection then it is very possible that your ISP prevents you from achieving your goals. Even if it was possible then you might be breaching your contract with them. I recommend giving them a call to see if they allow what you wish to do.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.